# Extracting bits from bytes

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am handling compressed data. The format contains a lookup table, and an array of long ints, which each may contain multiple values. Bit length of contained values varies depending on the file. I have access to these longs as `bytes` : is there an easy way to access a particular bit / bit range, or do I have to make one from scratch ? **Within the standard library**

Note that I may have to continue to the next long value when the bit length isn't a factor of 64.

---

Theoretical example of what the code needs to do :

- Take the long integer `4503672641818897L`
- Convert it to bits ( should return `0000000000010000000000000001000100000000000000000001000100010001` )
- Read the lookup table and determine how long the values are (let's say `5` bits this time)
- Read the 6th value, bits 25 - 29 (`00100`)
- Return the int value `4`

Comment: What do you mean by "should return `000...10001`"? Should it return a string, then you slice that string and interpret its slices as int again via `int("...00101", base=2)`?

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I don't care how it returns it as long as what is returned is indexable

Comment: Okay then, how about doing it like in the good old C times and use the `&` and `>>` operators for bitwise and and bitshifts? Let's say `a=17` (`010001`), `m=7` (`000111`) and `n=56` (`111000`), then `a&m` returns the last 3 bits (`1`) and `(a&n)>>3` the first three (`2`).

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I completely believe that this solution works but I also don't understand what the heck it's doing so I doubt I could use it :/

Comment: Numbers are just bits in memory (or at least that's what it's like in C and what Python emulates). By using the bitwise and operator (`&`) on two numbers, you create a new number where only the bits are 1, where they are 1 in both input numbers. So by using `&` with a bitmask like `000111`, the result can only retains the last 3 bits of the input. With `111000` it is a bit more tricky, because we want only the first three: `010111 & 111000` returns `010000`, but we only want the first three (`010`). Thus, we need to shift the result by three bits: `(...)>>3`.

Comment: Can you please clarify *what exactly* you are asking about? The question and theoretical example add a lot of "details" that can drastically change what you want – e.g. do you actually need the bits, or just "a function to get the n'th to k'th bit from some bytes", or "a function that takes the numbers and lookup table and index"? What is the result you want – bits, bytes, signed ints, unsigned ints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution not depending on external libraries like numpy or on string conversions:

```
def get_bits(num, start, end, length=64):
    '''Like bits(num)[from:to] interpreted as int'''
    mask = 2**(end-start)-1
    shift = length - (end-start) - start
    return (num & (mask << shift)) >> shift


print(get_bits(17, 0, 3, length=6))  # 010001[0:3] -> 010 = 2
print(get_bits(17, 3, 6, length=6))  # 010001[3:6] -> 001 = 1
print(get_bits(17, 0, 6, length=6))  # 010001[0:6] -> 010001 = 17
print(get_bits(4503672641818897, 25, 30))  # ...[25:30] -> 00100 = 4
```

Explanation:

- `mask = 2**(end-start)-1`: `end-start` is the number of bits to select (N), then `2**N` is a one with N zeros (2**3 -> 1000). `2**N - 1` then is N ones (1000 - 1 = 111).
- `shift = length - (end-start) - start`: The number of bits we want to shift the mask to the left (111 << 3 = 111000) and also the number of bits we want the result to shift to the right: 010001 & 111000 is 010000, we only want the first three bits. 010000 >> 3 is 010.
- `return (num & (mask << shift)) >> shift`: Now we put it all together

Comment: Seems to be the best solution so far, will accept if it passes my testing !

Comment: Does this always return a positive value ? The string conversion method does not work because python assumes (incorrectly) that the int is signed, and there's no way to change that

Comment: If `num` is a positive number, then the function works as expected. If your method of obtaining the integers returns negative integers and you want them to be interpreted as positive values, then you must handle that. If you need help with that, ask a separate question.

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work, but through no fault of your own. It seems the bits are encoded in REVERSE for some bizarre reason, which only seems manageable through string conversions. Since this wasn't part of the original problem, it's still accepted as the solution

Comment: Are all 64 bits of the `long` reversed, or are just the 8 bytes not in the order you had expected? Because then, the problem is the byte order ("endianness") and can maybe be handled directly by the routine reading the `long` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function `unpackbits` from `numpy`
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html

```py
Bits = numpy.unpackbits(Bytes)
```

Comment: I'd rather not add dependencies to my code, especially not requiring something as big as numpy for one function call

Answer (score -1):

What about this solution:

```py
unpacked = "{0:b}".format(long_int)
unpacked = "0"*(64-len(unpacked)) + unpacked
int(unpacked[25:30],2)
```

Comment: I'd rather not add dependencies to my code, nothing else needs numpy (*and I don't even know how to use numpy*)

Comment: Thank you ! It seems to be exactly equivalent to my current (janky) solution except the first step takes two lines instead of one

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT : DOES NOT WORK ! the int constructor assumes a signed int, and there is no way to tell it to construct a uint**

Here's a hacky solution I found. Seems very unwieldy though

```py
def bitValue(byteValue, start, length):
    """Extract length bits from byteValue at start, and return them as an integer"""
    return int(bin(byteValue).lstrip('0b').rjust(64, '0')[start:start+length], 2)
```

Comment: If you don't rely on performance, that's okay. But be aware that converting integers to strings, modifying them and converting the result back to integers is rather slow.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch I code in Python, of course performance is secondary x) If I need to sacrifice performance for readability I'll take that any day (which is why I don't use bitwise operations, I could figure out a solution but if I get anything wrong any debug would be super slow)

Comment: That's fine, of course. Readability is a big strength of Python and if string manipulation serves your purpose and way of thinking better than bit manipulation, then strings are the way to go :)